# Python: List Comprehension Destroys Selenium While Loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried scouring the bowels of the internet for an answer to this particular puzzle; however, I have not had too much luck with getting insight into this specific situation.

So, I am currently trying to scrape the last four or so pages of last.fm entries for "Jazz Metal" (see the URL).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)

driver.get('https://www.last.fm/tag/jazz+metal/artists?page=20')

super_list = []

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

while True:
    try:
        entries = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'grid-items-section'))
        )
        
        grid = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'grid-items-section')
        grid_children = grid.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')
        
        super_list.append(grid_children)
        
        pagination = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pagination-next'))
        )
        pagination.click()
                
    except:
        break
```

The thing is, `super_list.append(grid_children)` is not very helpful because once the while loop ends and I'm working with `super_list` outside of that scope, I can no longer call the `.text` method to get the contents and am only left with a list that's nearly indecipherable to a human.

> <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="11b49c8e-eec7-45f2->9e2a-e2034b93077a", element="ffe29b8e-5b65-4df3-985e-68e501e3a546")>

But, if I change `super_list.append(grid_children)` to `super_list.append([entry.text for entry in grid_children])`, the entire cookie crumbles. What gives? Also, if I remove `super_list.append(grid_children)` entirely, then it visits every page (yes, as it currently stands, it doesn't even visit the last page)!

The plot thickens, as if I include

```
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

then only the first page is visited. Can somebody please help me with this black magic?

Comment: entries doesn't seem to be used... you could just define grid there... grid_children is an array of webelement references.  Not all that useful to collect those references...  so maybe iterate through the array and use .text on each webelement reference to populate your "super_list"...

Comment: ...so "entries" and "grid" are the same.  This is because your expectedcondition returns the webelement if it is met... (otherwise false).  The webdriver wait passes that along (polling loop that returns the expectedconditions value if not false, or throws timeout if time is up).  So you can just use  grid = wait.until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'grid-items-section'))
        ) It seems like you want to loop over the grid children... to get your text values.

Comment: @pcalkins I didn't know that about expected_conditions, thanks for the tip. Of course, I know to iterate through the array and to use .text, but the whole point is that when I do that Selenium seems to hang up after the first page, sometimes not even scraping that either.

Comment: try/catch the .text call... see if an exception of "stale element" is thrown.  If so you have to get the array again.  You can either function-ize the call and re-call if stale element is thrown, or use a sleep of long enough time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I've officially given up on Selenium. I'm gonna go back to `requests-html`. Sorry to disappoint anybody who came here looking for a solution.